# There should not be any OP highlighting on Community Wiki questions

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, highlighting

[What are some useful keyboard shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242/what-are-some-useful-keyboard-shortcuts) is a community wiki question.

The OP [has commented below](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1242/what-are-some-useful-keyboard-shortcuts#comment1170_1242):

[image]

and their name is highlighted. It shouldn't be - they're not the poster any more, it's a collaborative question.

Comment: My [fairly exhaustive list of ways in which CW posts are still owned by their original poster](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306311/4099598) may be of interest. Spoiler: there's a lot. But it looks like this wasn't on there yet!

Answer (score 1):

I think the highlighting should remain.

Why? Because the OP of the question or answer is still the user that is notified on comments. It is still the one that is capable of performing some actions that are exclusive for the OP of a post. And besides that, it gives some context on the discussion going on in the comments.

So in short: The highlighting is useful.

Comment: So I guess my real feature request is that the OP *doesn't* have those powers.

Comment: I think that is an interesting discussion. What if the OP has only 1% of contribution left. Can you still consider him the 'author'? Maybe those privileges should be revoked when there is a contribution of more than X percent by other users?

Comment: Maybe if they have less than 100/No of contributors (i.e. they've contributed less than the average) probably with a minimum of 3 contributors?